# How to initialize File Upload dynamically?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

How to initialize this object dinamicly after click and bind this in template?

```
$scope.send = function(){

var setting = {};

var uploader = new FileUploader({
                    url: settings.path,
                    alias: settings.alias,
                    formData: settings.data,
                    autoUpload: true,
                    queueLimit: settings.limit
                });

}
```

Than object `uploader` will be available in template:

```
<div class="attachements" nv-file-drop="" uploader="uploader"></div>
```

Now, after loading page I get error, that `uploader` should be defined:

> TypeError: "Uploader" must be an instance of FileUploader

Comment: @ hAGARA can share the code in plunker ?

Comment: This is full code that I have in controller

Comment: The uploader object needs to be on scope. `$scope.uploader = new Fileuploader`.

Comment: I know but I need to uplad after click and set dinamicly path and data

Comment: So, I have form with element input, and button load file. I need to send form ever if files are not selectec. Submit form should be after ng-click element

Comment: Use [angular-file-saver](https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver)

Comment: What? this is not uploader